# Run Flask application with NGINX and Docker with Gunicorn

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn

I'm trying to run a Flask application in a docker container along with NGINX that is being used to route to the Flask application. I am using gunicorn as the server for the application and am having some trouble in my Docker Compose file to specify the gunicorn command. The problem I am facing, I believe, has something to do with my directory structure. Below is the tree structure I have:

```
    .
    ├── README.md
    ├── app
    │   ├── Dockerfile
    │   └── src
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── __pycache__
    │       │   └── server.cpython-39.pyc
    │       ├── requirements.txt
    │       └── server.py
    ├── docker-compose.yml
    ├── nginx
    │   ├── Dockerfile
    │   ├── files
    │   │   ├── localhost.crt
    │   │   └── localhost.key
    │   └── nginx.conf
    └── validate.sh
```

The `server.py` is the python file that holds the code for the Flask application. I am trying to use that in the gunicorn command but am getting the error that the module I am using is not found. Below is docker-compose file with specifications for the Flask container.

```
**Docker Compose**

version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    container_name: app
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 2 "src.server:index()"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    expose:
      - 8000
    networks:
      - MyNetwork
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      MyNetwork:
        aliases:
          - flask-app

networks:
  MyNetwork:
```

**docker-compose up output with updated error**

```
docker-compose up
Starting app_1 ... done
Starting nginx_1 ... done
Attaching to containerize_app_1, containerize_nginx_1
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:27:50 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:27:50 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:27:50 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:27:50 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:27:50 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:27:50 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
app_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
app_1    |     worker.init_process()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
app_1    |     self.load_wsgi()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
app_1    |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
app_1    |     self.callable = self.load()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
app_1    |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
app_1    |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
app_1    |     app = eval(obj, vars(mod))
app_1    |   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
app_1    |   File "/var/www/app/src/server.py", line 8, in index
app_1    |     request.headers.get('x-forwarded-for', None)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 432, in __get__
app_1    |     obj = instance._get_current_object()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 554, in _get_current_object
app_1    |     return self.__local()  # type: ignore
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 38, in _lookup_req_object
app_1    |     raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
app_1    | RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
app_1    | 
app_1    | This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
app_1    | an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
app_1    | information about how to avoid this problem.
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:27:50 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
nginx_1  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:27:50 +0000] [12] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
app_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
app_1    |     worker.init_process()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
app_1    |     self.load_wsgi()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
app_1    |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
app_1    |     self.callable = self.load()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
app_1    |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
app_1    |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
app_1    |     app = eval(obj, vars(mod))
app_1    |   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
app_1    |   File "/var/www/app/src/server.py", line 8, in index
app_1    |     request.headers.get('x-forwarded-for', None)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 432, in __get__
app_1    |     obj = instance._get_current_object()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 554, in _get_current_object
app_1    |     return self.__local()  # type: ignore
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 38, in _lookup_req_object
app_1    |     raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
app_1    | RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
app_1    | 
app_1    | This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
app_1    | an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
app_1    | information about how to avoid this problem.
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:27:50 +0000] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
nginx_1  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginx_1  | 2021/12/14 20:27:51 [emerg] 1#1: "user" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1
nginx_1  | nginx: [emerg] "user" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:27:51 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:27:51 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
containerize_nginx_1 exited with code 1
containerize_app_1 exited with code 3
```

**server.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    content = "Flask Server"
    fwd_for = "X-Forwarded-For: {}".format(
        request.headers.get('x-forwarded-for', None)
    )
    real_ip = "X-Real-IP: {}".format(
        request.headers.get('x-real-ip', None)
    )
    fwd_proto = "X-Forwarded-Proto: {}".format(
        request.headers.get('x-forwarded-proto', None)
    )

    output = "\n".join([content, fwd_for, real_ip, fwd_proto])
    response = make_response(output, 200)
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/plain"

    return response
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

ENV CONTAINER_HOME=/var/www

ADD . $CONTAINER_HOME
ADD src/* $CONTAINER_HOME
WORKDIR $CONTAINER_HOME

RUN pip install -r $CONTAINER_HOME/requirements.txt
```

Now I am getting this RuntimeError dealing with the request library of Flask.

Comment: What's in your Dockerfile?  Why do you need to override the `command:` for the normal case?  (I have a suspicion that your `volumes:` are mounting a different directory layout over the image content, and deleting the `volumes:` will help things along.)

Comment: So in my Dockerfile I do not have a "command" or "entry point" set. I figured if I specified that in the docker-compose that should be enough. After specifying the --chdir attribute it seems to be working better, but now I am being faced with some nginx directive errors. I'll update the question with my Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by specifying the following flag in the gunicorn command:`--chdir app/src`